# Getting OpenCV ObjectiveC++ errors while converting our swift app into Framework

Tags: swift, objective-c, opencv, frameworks, objective-c++

We are trying to convert our Swift app into framework, In our app we are using OpenCV library. So far we have resolved many compiler errors. Now we are stuck in resolving below OpenCV Objective C++ compiler error.

/Users/***/Desktop/Projects/**Framework/**Framework/OpenCV/OpenCV Neon/cvneon.h:15:29: No type named 'Mat' in namespace 'cv'

Below is our framework's header
[Please click here for issue snapshot in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTX11.png)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#import "exposure_compensate.hpp"
#endif

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//! Project version number for NewFrameworkV36.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double NewFrameworkV36VersionNumber;

//! Project version string for NewFrameworkV36.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char NewFrameworkV36VersionString[];

#import "RenderingModel.h"
#import "Helper.h"
#import "TJSpinner.h"

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```